# Computer-Keyboard properties

Tags: 14.04

Trying out Live Version of Ubuntu 14 LTS.
But the computer-keyboard-keys are in US-format. How can I change this to a german format?
Ricky

Comment: You switch to a different layout, for example to german.

Comment: Have you perhaps checked system settings - keyboard/text entry ?